# How can i simplify this java Statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement

```
private void clean(View v) {
    ColorDrawable color = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.white));
    if (v.getId() == R.id.nav_news){
        nav_feed_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_profile_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_chat_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_books_bg.setBackground(color);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.nav_feed){
        nav_news_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_profile_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_chat_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_books_bg.setBackground(color);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.nav_profile){
        nav_feed_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_news_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_chat_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_books_bg.setBackground(color);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.nav_chat){
        nav_feed_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_profile_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_news_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_books_bg.setBackground(color);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.nav_books){
        nav_feed_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_profile_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_chat_bg.setBackground(color);
        nav_news_bg.setBackground(color);
    }
}
```

How can i Simplify this Statement there are 5 Views If One View is Called We have to set white Background to Other Views with White Color Bg

Edit :

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Drawable shadow;
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.nav_news:
                Utils.sToast(this, "NavBar Item Clicked 1");
                shadow = getDrawable(R.drawable.shadow_bg_nav);
                clean(v);
                nav_news_bg.setBackground(shadow);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_feed:
                Utils.sToast(this, "NavBar Item Clicked 2");
                shadow = getDrawable(R.drawable.shadow_bg_nav);
                clean(v);
                nav_feed_bg.setBackground(shadow);
                break;
            ... Other Statements Here
}
```

These May be Helpful for Answering I always try to Optimize my code but Some Statements like these makes Ugly Repetitive Blocks

Comment: would be better on codereview SE as there isn't actually an issue with it working

Comment: is your all views in same layout??

Comment: Is cleanV a typo and should refer to clean(View v), or is it other not relevant call?

Comment: sorry for that its a typo corrected it now it is because i was trying various answers so various methods created for that issue in java file without changing old method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Where do You set color for the selected item? is it possible to set all colors to white and then use switch to set only the selected one to desired color?
It would make it at least more pleasant to look at.

```
nav_news_bg.setBackground(color);
nav_feed_bg.setBackground(color);
nav_profile_bg.setBackground(color);
nav_chat_bg.setBackground(color);
nav_books_bg.setBackground(color);

switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.nav_news:
        nav_news_bg.setBackground(desiredColor);
        break;
    case R.id.nav_feed:
    .
    .
    .
}
```

After Your edit it would be best to drop any logic from clean and leave it only as

```
private void clean(View v) {
    ColorDrawable color = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.white));
    nav_news_bg.setBackground(color);
    nav_feed_bg.setBackground(color);
    nav_profile_bg.setBackground(color);
    nav_chat_bg.setBackground(color);
    nav_books_bg.setBackground(color);
}
```

because background color is set after this method is executed.

Comment: May Be Not Recommended This can reduce the Complexity and Optimize my Code is there any possibility Optimize it some more with memory concent

Comment: From code You provided and assumin that cleanV() is in fact clean(), you cant drop the switch from clean and just use it  for resetting everything to white, as setting the proper background is next call in line. Also think about making white color static, there is no need to create and garbage an instance for every click.

Answer (score 1):

Since the crux of your logic is "set the background of all views except the one being called" Why not try

```
if (v.getId() != R.id.nav_news) nav_feed_news.setBackground(color);
if (v.getId() != nav_feed) nav_feed.setBackground(color);
// and so on for the rest.
```

Comment: the above code is for custom navBar views here are linear layouts so when i click it holds backgound while selecting other menu can you get it

Answer (score -1):

```
Map<Integer, View> views = new HashMap();
public void MyClass() {
   init();
   views.put(R.id.nav_news, nav_news_bg);
   views.put(R.id.nav_profile, nav_profile_bg);
   // etc
}
private void clean(View v) {
    Colour colour = ... 
    for (Map.Entry entry : views) {
       if (!entry.getKey().equals(v.getId()) {
           entry.getValue().setbackground(color);
       } 
   } 
}
```